# Can we put html inside Route element?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
 <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Navbar />} />

      <Route path='/' element={<div className='recipes'>
        {query ? query.map((object, i) => (
          <RecipeCard
            src={object.src}
            ingredients={object.ingredients}
            steps={object.steps}
            key={i}
          />
        )) : "Loading"}
      </div>}/>
      
      <Route path='/' element={<Details />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
```

For example in the above code, I want to render the HTML along with the Route element.
I am not getting the 2nd and 3rd Route tags displayed on my localhost. Where is my mistake?
What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Yes, using [<Outlet />](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet). Check out the [nested routes tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#nested-routes).

Comment: @DennisMartinez can you point out errors in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only requirement is that the `element` prop takes a `React.ReactNode`. In other words, it takes any valid JSX.

The issue though is that there can only be one route per path. Your code is trying to render 3 routes on the same `"/"` path. Just unconditionally render the `Navbar` and `Details` components ***not*** on a route.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Navbar />
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path='/'
      element={(
        <div className='recipes'>
          {query 
            ? query.map((object, i) => (
              <RecipeCard
                src={object.src}
                ingredients={object.ingredients}
                steps={object.steps}
                key={i}
              />))
            : "Loading"
          }
        </div>
      )}
    />
  </Routes>
  <Details />
</Router>
```

If you are wanting to ***conditionally*** render `Navbar` and `Details` on ***only*** certain routes then create a layout route component.

- [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes)
- [Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet)

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render element content here
    <Details />
  </>
);
```

Render the routes you want to have the navbar and details as nested routes, and for the routes you don't want them render these as sibling routes.

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<Layout />}>
      <Route
        path='/'
        element={(
          <div className='recipes'>
            {query
              ? query.map((object, i) => (
                <RecipeCard
                  src={object.src}
                  ingredients={object.ingredients}
                  steps={object.steps}
                  key={i}
                />))
              : "Loading"
            }
          </div>
        }
      />
      ...other routes with Navbar and Details...
    </Route>

    ...other routes w/o Navbar and Details...
  </Routes>
</Router>
```